# Calling C code from C++ in a CMake project. Undefined symbol. Have extern C

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, extern, calling-convention

I'm trying to build a CMake project that calls C code from C++, and I'm getting undefined symbols, even though I'm (AFAIK) properly using "extern C".

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(CTest LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(test main.cpp lib.c)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "lib.h"

int main()
{
    printit();
    return 0;
}
```

lib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"

int printit()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

lib.h:

```
extern "C" int printit();
```

That gives me an "undefined reference to printit" error.

If I simply build this from the command-line, it works fine:

```
g++ main.cpp lib.c
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you have both C and CXX sources you should use `project(CTest LANGUAGES C CXX)` in your CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`extern "C"` is C++ syntax. Your header lib.h therefore cannot be used from C. If you change it as follows it can be used from C++ and C as well.

```
#ifndef LIB_H_HEADER
#define LIB_H_HEADER

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif

int printit();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* LIB_H_HEADER */
```

As you have both C and CXX sources your project call should enable C as well `project(CTest LANGUAGES C CXX)` in your CMakeLists.txt.