# Don't link *.c and *.cpp files in cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I can not understand why files *.c and *.cpp in cmake do not build.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(task2_cmake LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(task2_cmake main.cpp src/lib.c)
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "src/lib.h"

int main()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

**lib.h**

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void print();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // LIB_H
```

**lib.c**

```
#include "lib.h"

void print()
{
    int a;
}
```

error: undefined reference to `print'

The project has many similar libraries (*.c)
I do not want to rename to *.cpp

Comment: If you do not want to rename your files to `*.cpp`, then create another project for `lib` and link that project as a dependency.

Comment: Did you try adding C to the list of languages? . `project(task2_cmake LANGUAGES CXX C)`

Comment: You are trying to compile C++ **and** C code, so you need to enable the `C` language in CMake also: `project(task2_cmake LANGUAGES C CXX)`. In fact, CMake enables `C` and `CXX` *by default*, so you really can just put `project(task2_cmake)`. See the duplicate question and response here: [Calling C code from C++ in a CMake project. Undefined symbol. Have extern C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280003/calling-c-code-from-c-in-a-cmake-project-undefined-symbol-have-extern-c)